# I am having issue in divi woocomerce checkout module

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes, divi

(theme: Divi) I added 4 modules in the woocommerce checkout page like checkout information, billing details, payment mode, and additional information. when any payment order is pending and the user is paying payment from my account > order > padding order so the user is gating multiple payment options of one payment option like Paypal. I attached an image of the error page. and this is the link ->  https://ibb.co/GtvmrPT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You need to provide the relevant code in your post for other contributors to help you. This link provides guidelines on how to create a Minimal Reproducible Example in your post >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I contacted Divi support and they replied to me. they told me that Divi is still improving wc_moduls and releasing that fix in the new update.